# Error with creating object at point of mouseclick, cannot spot the error in the code at all

Tags: java, swing, mouseclick-event

I was wondering if you could help me spot whats wrong with my code, I basically need to generate a ball at the point of mouseclick, but for some reason its not working. I managed to get a ball populating from the default point only. I've been trawling the interwebs for hours and honestly can't spot what's wrong.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xvel = 1;
    int yvel =1;



    //code to generate a random colour for the balls
    Random rand = new Random();
        float r = rand.nextFloat();
        float g = rand.nextFloat();
        float b = rand.nextFloat();
        Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);


    private void moveBall() {
        if (x + xvel < 0)
            xvel = 1;
        if (x + xvel > getWidth() - 30)
            xvel = -1;
        if (y + yvel < 0)
            yvel = 1;
        if (y + yvel > getHeight() - 30)
            yvel = -1;

        x = x + xvel;
        y = y + yvel;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x = this.getX();
        y = this.getY();
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(randomColor);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BallProject");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);




        while (true) {
            game.moveBall();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }







    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never register `Game` as a responder to mouse events...

```
public Game() {
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

See [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.

You're also using the components x/y position and not the mouse clicks...

```
x = this.getX();
y = this.getY();
```

Instead, use

```
x = arg0.getX();
y = arg0.getY();
```

I'd also, generally, advise against overriding `paint` as a general rule and suggest using `paintComponent` instead

You "game loop" is also in danger of violating the single thread rules of Swing on two accounts.

1. You don't know what `Thread` main is been called in, you should not risk starting an infinite loop within it.  Also, you should make sure that the UI is created within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details
2. You are modifying the state of the `x`/`y` variables outside of the context of the EDT, but these values are required by the EDT to paint the results, this could lead to a race condition which may produce random and undesirable results.